# ADFS 2.0 sign-in posts truncated for small number of Internet Explorer users

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, wif, adfs2.0

We have a fairly large site (500k + auth users) using ADFS2 as an (passive auth) authentication portal and several ASP.NET / C# websites using WIF that trust this portal.

For a very small number of users that are running IE (9,10,11?) they log on ok at the ADFS login site but on the resulting authentication post to the WIF site they get an error that the XML is invalid.

We logged the traffic to see what was happening and the SAML token is actually being truncated - it is ending up with

```
</saml:AttributeStatementnticationStatement
```

in the post instead of

```
</saml:AttributeStatement><saml:AuthenticationStatement
```

This is pretty much a stock install of ADFS and WIF - nothing fancy. We cannot duplicate the error ourselves despite having tried multiple version of IE running on multiple OS's

The error is pretty rare but for users that experience it - it appears to be consistent - ie, they can never login to one of the WIF based sites and the truncation so far at least looks like it's always happening at the same point.

Switching to another browser fixes the problem (ie, Chrome, Firefox) so the evidence so far looks like this is an IE specific issue, but there is something that we cannot duplicate.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What content type is the server sending and what encoding. We had similar problem when by mistake we sent encoding `utf8` and not `utf-8`. It affected only IE browsers and the occurrence was rare.

Comment: that's an interesting point. I'll confirm the values in the headers and page data are in agreement and specified correctly.

Comment: that doesn't appear to be the issue. character encoding looks good- still getting errors